# nested WITH statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

That works:

```
; with res1 as (
        select 1 as col1
    )
select * from res1
```

How to nest a WITH statement one inside another? I tried

```
; with res1 as (
    ; with res2 as (
        select 1 as col1
    ) 
    select * from res2
    )
select * from res1
```

but I get an error:

> ```
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
> Incorrect syntax near ';'.
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
> Incorrect syntax near ')'.
> ```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Maybe there is a different way.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "MSSQL" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1413516/6655648 is a very similar question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can do it as follows:

```
; with res1 as (
        select 1 as col1
    ),
    res2 as(
    select * from res1
    )
select * from res2
```