# Average salary per Department

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm doing Intro to SQL and I'm currently doing this exercise, but I'm stuck.

Exercise:

> Create a list of department names, the manager id, manager name( employee last name) of that department, and the average salary in each department.

Below is the schema of the exercise, just the tables that I'm using.

```
CREATE TABLE  "EMPLOYEES"
("EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER(6,0),
"FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(20),
"LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT "EMP_LAST_NAME_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
"EMAIL" VARCHAR2(25) CONSTRAINT "EMP_EMAIL_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
"PHONE_NUMBER" VARCHAR2(20),
"HIRE_DATE" DATE CONSTRAINT "EMP_HIRE_DATE_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
"JOB_ID" VARCHAR2(10) CONSTRAINT "EMP_JOB_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
"SALARY" NUMBER(8,2),
"COMMISSION_PCT" NUMBER(2,2),
"MANAGER_ID" NUMBER(6,0),
"DEPARTMENT_ID" NUMBER(4,0),
"BONUS" VARCHAR2(5),
 CONSTRAINT "EMP_SALARY_MIN" CHECK (salary > 0) ENABLE,
 CONSTRAINT "EMP_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("EMPLOYEE_ID")
USING INDEX  ENABLE,
 CONSTRAINT "EMP_EMAIL_UK" UNIQUE ("EMAIL")
USING INDEX  ENABLE
);

CREATE TABLE  "DEPARTMENTS"
("DEPARTMENT_ID" NUMBER(4,0),
"DEPARTMENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT "DEPT_NAME_NN" NOT NULL ENABLE,
"MANAGER_ID" NUMBER(6,0),
"LOCATION_ID" NUMBER(4,0),
 CONSTRAINT "DEPT_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("DEPARTMENT_ID")
USING INDEX  ENABLE
);
```

This is what I have now,

```
select  d.department_name, d.manager_id,e.last_name as "manager_name" , 
avg(salary)
from departments d join employees e ON (e.employee_id=d.manager_id)
group by d.department_name,e.last_name, d.manager_id;
```

I was able to generate all the fields it asked for except for the average, I did get the answer by doing a separate query

```
 select department_name, round(avg(salary)) from employees e join 
 departments d ON (e.department_id=d.department_id)
 group by department_name;
```

I can't figure out for the life of me, how to make it so that the select statement that gives me the average salary works, I attempted HAVING clause which doesn't work because it limit what its already given. Hopefully someone can explain to me what I'm missing. Appreciate the responses!

Comment: what database server are you using?

Comment: Oracle SQL database

Answer (score 2):

Because employees serves to cite both managers and non-managers, and departments have a manager, you have to join the employees table to departments TWICE in the same SQL. Youre looking for both these joins in the same sql:

---

This join will associate manager details with the department:

```
departments inner join employees mgrs on departments.manager_id = mgrs.employee_id
```

---

This join will associate employees with a department

```
departments inner join employees emps on emps.department_id = departments.department_id
```

---

So, your ultimate sql will have the following somewhere in it:

```
FROM
 departments
 INNER JOIN employees mgrs ON ....
 INNER JOIN employees emps ON ....
WHERE
```

Confused? Consider another example relevant to you. You have an address where you live and an address where you work. If it were a database it would probably have tables `persons` and `addresses`. It wouldn't have `persons`, `home_addresses` and `work_addresses` because a home/work address is just an address. Persons table might have a `home_address_id` and a `work_address_id` for you though and a different ID in each column, pointing to 2 different address rows in the addresses. This means there's no way to join addresses in just once and get both your work and your home address. Logically, it doesn't work: if there's only one set of address columns, which data is it showing - your work or your home? You can't show two values on top of each other in one cell, no.. You have to add more cells. We add more cells onto the right of an existing block of cells by... Doing another join! If you want to have columns in your select list of:

```
person.Name,
homeaddress.Street,
workaddress.Street
```

Then address has to be joined in twice.

```
Person table
------------
Name      Home_Address_Id Work_Address_Id
JohnSmith 1               2

Address table
-------------
ID Building    Street
1  261         Great Hope Street
2  Office2000  Commercial Way
```

Hopefully it's also clear to see that your addresses for work and home are different (you work in the city, and live in the country, ok? no home-working allowed ;) ), so you can't say:

```
person p INNER JOIN address a ON p.home_address_id = a.id AND p.work_address_id = a.id
```

Because when the database joins the two tables together, before it processes your ON conditions, it joins all rows to all rows (conceptually) then it filters

```
Persons-Joined-To-Addresses
---------------------------
Name      Home_Address_Id Work_Address_Id ID Building    Street
JohnSmith 1               2               1  261         Great Hope Street
JohnSmith 1               2               2  Office2000  Commercial Way
```

You can see that there isn't ANY row that satisfied both conditions, because the database scans the rows it has generated, testing for any that satisfy all the ON conditions:

```
Does 1=1 and 2=1? No. Do not include the 'JohnSmith 1               2               1  261         Great Hope Street' row
Does 1=2 AND 2=2? No. Do not include the 'JohnSmith 1               2               2  Office2000  Commercial Way' row
```

If you join the addresses in TWICE though, well that's different:

```
Persons-Joined-To-Addresses-Joined-To-Addresses-Again
-----------------------------------------------------
Name      Home_Address_Id Work_Address_Id IH BuildingH   StreetH           IW BuildingW   StreetW
JohnSmith 1               2               1  261         Great Hope Street 1  261         Great Hope Street
JohnSmith 1               2               1  261         Great Hope Street 2  Office2000  Commercial Way
JohnSmith 1               2               2  Office2000  Commercial Way    1  261         Great Hope Street
JohnSmith 1               2               2  Office2000  Commercial Way    2  Office2000  Commercial Way
```

Of these 4 rows, there is only one that satisfies the condition for the joins. Here's the list of test the database does:

```
Does 1=1 and 2=1? No. Don't include the 'JohnSmith/Great Hope Street/Great Hope Street' row
Does 1=1 and 2=2? YES. Include the 'JohnSmith/Great Hope Street/Commercial Way' row
Does 1=2 AND 2=1? No. Do not include the 'JohnSmith/Commercial Way/Great Hope Street' row
Does 1=2 AND 2=2? No. Do not include the 'JohnSmith/Commercial Way/Commercial Way' row
```

The two conditions are the same as before but I've renamed the ID columns as IH and IW. The conditions are `home_address_id = IH and work_address_id = IW`.  It's very important that you grasp the notion in the 'Does a=b AND x=y?' rows above that you appreciate that we're treating address IDs differently by attaching a meaning of "home" or "work" to them. Were saying:

> Does person.**home**_address_id=id_from_addresses_**aliased_as_home** AND person.**work**_address_id=id_from_addresses_**aliased_as_work**?

---

After you get this into one sql, summing the salaries of employees will work. Make sur you alias the employees table differently for each join. I called mine mgrs and emps so I know whether the data is "manager level" or "employee level"

I haven't written the whole query for you because this is clearly a homework exercise, but if you need more help, post comments :)

Comment: Appreciate your response btw! :)

Comment: initially I did have from departments d join employees e ON (e.employee_id=d.manager_id) AND (e.department_id = d.department_id) and its giving me the same answer.

Comment: but that just joins the employees table in once, on rows that satisfy both conditions... When i say "the SQL has to join the table in twice" I literally mean it has to have a text like `department inner join employees mgr on ... inner join employees emp ON ...` i.e. if you did Ctrl+F for "inner join employees" it would say `2 occurrences found`

Comment: select  d.department_name, d.manager_id,emps.last_name as "manager_name" , avg(emps.salary)
from departments d
join employees emps ON (emps.employee_id=d.manager_id)
join employees mgrs ON (mgrs.department_id = d.department_id)
group by d.department_name, d.manager_id, emps.last_name;


same answer

Comment: Read what you wrote closely; there's a reason  why I called the employees tables EMPS for employees and MGRS for managers. Are you certain you've joined these tables on correctly ? When joining a table in twice it's vital to name things properly to avoid tying yourself in knots

Comment: i'm trying to understand how it would calculate salary with another join added. I'm really trying. to understand

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
select d.department_name, d.manager_id,e.last_name as "manager_name", avg(salary)
from departments d join employees e ON (e.employee_id=d.manager_id)
group by d.department_name,d.manager_id, e.last_name ;
```

Comment: It would be better to explain what this does differently and why you think it may answer the question.

Comment: it came up with the same answer as what I had, just the group by order was changed. It does not give the average per department.

Comment: Can you post an example answer?

Comment: no luck, still the same issue. everything is good except for the average. not sure what its doing there..

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH DINFO AS (SELECT departments.department_name,departments.department_id,departments.manager_id,ROUND(AVG(salary)) AS AVGSAL
FROM departments
INNER JOIN employees ON (employees.department_id = departments.department_id)
GROUP BY departments.department_name,departments.department_id,departments.manager_id
)

SELECT DINFO.department_name,DINFO.manager_id,last_name, DINFO.AVGSAL FROM employees e, DINFO
WHERE e.employee_id = DINFO.manager_id;
```

Comment: The "WITH" method provides you the computed results of the GROUP BY clause. To JOIN all together without the "WITH" method will give you only the AVG(salary) of the manager, this is the normal monthly salary of the manager, not the AVG(salary) of the departments. You only can get the AVG(salary) of the department to fetch it from the virtual table DINFO( in my example it is named DINFO ...departmentsinfo). Best regards and happy coding.

Comment: A great article about [nested WITH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413516/can-you-create-nested-with-clauses-for-common-table-expressions)  clauses is on stackoverflow, which shows you the whole power and abilities of this method.

Comment: In this example, it is neccessary to know first: what joins are doing, we have enough descriptions in this blog, but second: it is really nesseccary to know,    [how group by works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7434657/how-does-group-by-work) I found it on stackoverflow. If you do not know, what group by is doing, you do not know what you have to expect as result.