# Truly nested CTEs in T-SQL / SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, t-sql, common-table-expression

From Postgres I am used to do:

```
with a as (
 with b as (
  SELECT
  ...
 )
 SELECT
 ...
),
c as (
 SELECT
 ...
)
SELECT
...
```

This type of nesting (or CTE hierarchy) of a & b  does not execute in T-SQL however.

Is there a workaround for this, a simple rewrite as suggested in [Can you create nested WITH clauses for Common Table Expressions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1413516/can-you-create-nested-with-clauses-for-common-table-expressions) like

```
with a as (
 SELECT
 ...
 ),
b as (
 SELECT
 ...
),
c as (
 SELECT
 ...
)
SELECT
...
```

is not possible in my case (see query below), as in many other cases.

Would be glad for some pointers since I am new to T-SQL.

---

```
--generate a time-series in 15min intervals, ending with the last incoming user
WITH last_timeslot AS (
--get the last ts from one of the two tables with less recent entries
    SELECT
        dateadd(
            MINUTE,
                datediff(
                    MINUTE,
                    0,
                    LEAST(
                        (SELECT
                            MAX(ts)
                        FROM dbo.user u )
                        ,
                        (SELECT
                            MAX(ts)
                        FROM dbo.user_history uh )
                    )
                )/ 15 * 15, --round to 15min slot
            0
        ) AS last_timeslot_ts
),
timeslot_series AS (
    --recursively generate a timeseries going back 14 days from the last timeslot, in 15min steps
    WITH cte AS (
      SELECT DATEADD(DAY,-14,(SELECT last_timeslot_ts FROM last_timeslot)) AS slot
      UNION ALL
      SELECT  DATEADD(MINUTE,15,slot) 
      FROM    cte   
      WHERE   DATEADD(MINUTE,15,slot) < (SELECT last_timeslot_ts FROM last_timeslot)
    )
    SELECT  slot
    FROM    cte
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
),
c as (
--other stuff happens
SELECT
...
FROM timeslot_series
LEFT JOIN
...
)
SELECT ...
```

Comment: You can't nest CTEs, as you've been advised previously. You need to define them like you were shown and you demonstrate in the second example. Also `OPTION` goes at the *very end* of your query, not the middle of it. There's, however, no need for an rCTe here; use a Tally they are *significantly* faster. Perhaps if you get rid of the recursion problem your misunderstanding will be eliminated. Finally, there is no `LEAST` function in T-SQL.

Comment: Why rewrite is not possible? Such nesting is quite unreadable, so it is a good time for redesign

Comment: In my opinion, the first way of nesting CTEs makes no sense to begin with. What are you trying to achieve with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll simplify to two levels of nesting, because it's enough to demonstrate the solution. We start with this:

```
with a as (
 with b as (
  SELECT
  ...
 )
 SELECT
 ...
),
SELECT
...
```

Presumably, `a` needs to reference `b` as part of it's query. So when we try to un-nest them and instead list them in serial as below it doesn't work yet:

```
with a as (
 SELECT
 ...
 ),
b as (
 SELECT
 ...
),
SELECT
...
```

To fix this, we need to *reverse the order* in which we define each CTE. That is, define the inner-most levels of the query as a CTE first, and then work outwards:

```
with b as (
 SELECT
 ...
 ),
a as (
 SELECT
 ...
),
SELECT
...
```

Now you will be able to reference `b` within `a` (and again in the final SELECT, if needed). If we were to go back to the original example and include `c` again, it would now come first, followed by `b`, and then `a`.